# Editar un carácter de un .txt (Archivo) en Java

Tags: java, archivo, txt, filewriter, filereader

mi problema es que programando con el "FileWriter" para editar un txt, no soy capaz de poder editar un carácter de una linea o columna concreta de este archivo.

**Por ejemplo**

*(Contenido del archivo .txt)*

```
Nombre;Edad;0
Nombre1;Edad1;0
Nombre2;Edad2;0
```

*(Lo que quiero editar)*

Supongamos que quiero editar el numero '0' por un 3 de las filas 1 y 2. Intenté usar el FileWriter pero el problema es que me edita la linea del txt completo y no la fila, columna y carácter específico.

¿Alguien sabe como decirle al programa que edite específicamente ese carácter y/o linea del .txt?
Gracias!

Comment: Podrías por favor adicionar el código que tienes y que falla? adicionalmente, podrías poner un ejemplo del valor que esperas?

Comment: Lo que a priori se me ocurre es que si ese Nombre y esa Edad son algún valor en concreto puedes detectarlos y automáticamente ponerles los valores que quieres.

Comment: Y como para qué te serviría modificarlo? tus daatos serán solamente texto o también habrá información binaria en tu texto? que codificación tiene tu txt? cuál es el peso de tu archivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el `FileWriter` no sé si es posible cambiar concretamente solo una parte.
Pero sí lo puedes hacer con `RandomAccessFile`.

Te dejo un ejemplo simplificado.
Para empezar, escribiremos con el FileWriter lo que queremos introducir en nuestro fichero.
En tu caso:

Para escribir:

```
try {
         FileWriter f=new FileWriter("hola");
         f.write("Nombre; edad ");
         f.close();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Xxxx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
```

Para leer:

```
 try {
         FileReader f=new FileReader("hola");
         char x=(char)f.read();
         System.out.print(x);
         while(x!=-1){
            x=(char)f.read();
            System.out.print(x);
         }
         f.close();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Xxxx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Xxxx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
```

Para leer con Random:

```
try {
           RandomAccessFile fi=new RandomAccessFile("hola","rw"); //rw = read, write.
           fi.seek(0); //para situarnos al principio del fichero
           System.out.println((char)fi.readByte());
           System.out.println((char)fi.readByte());
           System.out.println((char)fi.readByte());
           System.out.println((char)fi.readByte());
           fi.close();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Xxxx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Xxxx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
```

Notese que para leer con un Random lo puedes hacer con un bucle, pero te lo pongo así para que sea más visual para tí.

Entonces tendríamos 2 opciones:

- 1. Leemos la fila, y la guardamos en una char array. Desde la array cambiamos la
     posición que queremos, y la volvemos a escribir con el fileWriter.
- 2. Otra solución como he comentado anteriormente, sería utilizar el ``RandomAccesFile´´

Y así lo cambiaríamos:
(Sabemos que un char se representa con 1 byte, un int con 4 bytes. Si queremos cambiar la primera posición...)

```
try {
           RandomAccessFile fi=new RandomAccessFile("hola","rw");
           fi.seek(0);
           fi.writeInt(fi.getFilePointer()-4); //restamos 4 bytes a la posición en la que 
                                               //nos encontramos. Volveremos a la posición 
                                               // 0, donde ahora está el numero 10.
           
           System.out.println((int)fi.readInt());
           fi.close();

       } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Xxxx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Xxxx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
    }
```

Entonces, para tu solución, tendrás que ir sumando y restando bytes, o hacer la opción 1.

Hay muchas más soluciones, pero estas han sido las que se me han ocurrido, espero ayudarte. :)